# How can I override superclass property with different type

Tags: swift

As title.
I know. I can use [AnyObject] instead of type variable, But I just want to prevent a lots of type checking in swift.
And now, I don't have any idea about this problem. Does anyone can help me. Thanks

```
class TypeA: NSObject {
    var name: String
    ........
}
class TypeB: TypeA {
    .........
}
class ObjectA {
     var type = [TypeA]()
}
class ObjectB: ObjectA {
     override var type = [TypeB]() <---Cannot override a property "type"
}
```

Question update: Thanks guys and reference to "R Menke"'s code

```
class TypeA: NSObject {
    override init() {
        print("typeA")
    }
}
class TypeB: TypeA {
    override init() {
        print("typeB")
    }
}
class ObjectA<T:TypeA> {
    var type = [T]()
    init(type:T) {
        self.type.append(type)
       print("objectA")
    }

    func addNewType() {
        let newType = TypeA()
        self.type.append(newType)  <-- compiler complaints at here
    }

}
class ObjectB<T:TypeA>: ObjectA<T> {
    override init(type:T) {
        super.init(type: type)
       print("objectB")
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed with @RMenke. This almost always suggests a misuse of subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` generic classes.

```
class ObjectA<T:TypeA> {
    var type = [T]()
```

Now the `type` attribute will always be a `TypeA` or a subclass of `TypeA`.
But you no longer need to downcast to find out what type it is.

```
class TypeA: NSObject {
    override init() {
        print("typeA")
    }
}
class TypeB: TypeA {
    override init() {
        print("typeB")
    }
}
class ObjectA<T:TypeA> {
    var type = [T]()
    init(type:T) {
        self.type.append(type)
        print("objectA")
    }
}
class ObjectB<T:TypeA>: ObjectA<T> {
    override init(type:T) {
        super.init(type: type)
        print("objectB")
    }
}

let tA = TypeA()
let tB = TypeB()
let oA = ObjectA(type: tA) // ObjectA<TypeA>
let oB = ObjectB(type: tB) // ObjectB<TypeB>
```

---

Or just make `ObjectA` generic :

`ObjectB` will now work as a specialiser for `ObjectA`, it is not generic itself, but does put a constraint on it's superclass. Now you can use it like any other class but it's `type` property will have `TypeB` as type instead of `TypeA`

```
class ObjectA<T:TypeA> {
    var type = [T]()
    init(type:T) {
        self.type.append(type)
        print("objectA")
    }
}
class ObjectB: ObjectA<TypeB> {
    override init(type:TypeB) {
        super.init(type: type)
        print("objectB")
    }
}
```

Comment: But I still cannot add any element to type array using function                   func appendType() {
        let newType = TypeA()
        self.type.append(newType)}

Comment: @CocoaUser Can you post an example of that function in an update to your question andinclude which class it is a part of.

Answer (score 2):

@RMenke is completely correct here, but it's also important to understand why it's true. This isn't a limitation of Swift. This is a fundamental issue of what subclasses mean.

Let's pretend for a moment that you *could* do what you're asking for. If that were true, the following code would be legal:

```
let objA: ObjectA = ObjectB()
objA.type.append(ObjectA())
```

I have to be allowed to treat `ObjectB` as if it were an `ObjectA`. That's what the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) means for subtyping. So now I'm allowed to add an `ObjectA` to an `[ObjectB]`. That breaks the whole type system. Blam.

Generally when you want this, it's because you're misusing subclasses. Subclasses are seldom the right tool in pure Swift; they mostly creep in because of bridging to ObjC. But even in ObjC, subclassing should be avoided when possible. Swift brings us excellent new tools to help avoid subclasses, and you should prefer them. For example, rather than subclassing, just use protocols:

```
protocol A {}
struct TypeA: A {}
struct TypeB: A {}

class Object<T: A> {
    var type = [T]()
}
```

Comment: This falls apart when the protocol has an associatedtype.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `A` can have an associated type in this example. You may want to open a new question addressing your specific case.

Comment: Instantiating `Object` requires a concrete type. If `A` has an `associatedtype`, it can't be used. Assuming `TypeA` and `TypeB` both have a `typealias` for the `associatedtype`, only one can be used. `Object.type` in this case can only store `TypeA` or `TypeB` but not both.

Comment: Correct; it can store only `TypeA` or `TypeB`, but `A` itself can have an associated type. The deeper point is it's not possible to `[A]` at all if `A` is a PAT, but that isn't the issue in the original question (which is about subclassing). The solution to `[A]` for a PAT is to use a type eraser (`AnyA`), and that the general solution to that entire class of problem (not just around subclassing or generics).

Comment: Type erasure assumes each implementation of `A` to have the same `typealias`. `TypeA` and `TypeB` would still need to have the same `typealias`. A great example I came across is if there's a protocol `Vehicle { associatedtype EngineType }`. Each implementation of `Vehicle` could have different `EngineType`. Type erasure wouldn't work in this instance. `class Truck: Vehicle { typealias EngineType = V8Engine }` and `class Car: Vehicle { typealias EngineType = V6Engine }` are still not compatible in a type erasure class of `AnyVehicle<Engine>` due to the engines being different.

Comment: To expand, let's say I want an `Array<Vehicle>` with each `Vehicle` having their own engine types, yet all I care about is the fact that each `Vehicle` has a method `startIgnition`. Type erasure doesn't solve the issue of each implementation of `Vehicle` having their own engine type, yet share the same interface of "starting the engine" the same way.

Comment: This isn't a good use of protocols. Vehicle should be a struct that HAS-A Engine. *Engine* could be a protocol, but probably should also just be a struct. These aren't "protocol-like things."

Comment: I completely disagree that they should not be protocols and should only be structs. If a car is already started, and it can be stopped, it should not be a value type. There should be one reference that's passed around. A `Vehicle` protocol makes complete sense in my mind. It has requirements that any implementation must provide. A `Vehicle` should always have an `Engine`, but each `Engine` type can be different. I can provide another example without `Vehicle` and `Engine`, but I feel this illustrates the lack of features Swift has to take care of these details.

Comment: The feature you're looking for here is class, not protocol. In Swift, reference types that allow multiple implementations are classes. As you note, and I agree, Swift protocols are badly suited to this problem. Whether it is a current lack of features, or because the language never intends this to be a good match, is not really clear yet (IMO to anyone). But in Swift 3 and 4, protocols aren't useful here.

Comment: Using a class is limited due to the inability to override an `Engine` type property in a subclass. The property `engine: Engine` on `Vehicle` could not be overridden on a subclass due to limitations in Swift. I've heard arguments about safety, but in reality `V8Engine` is still an `Engine`. One option is to add a new property to the subclass that would coerce the `engine: Engine` to be a type the subclass wants: `class Truck: Vehicle { var v8Engine { return engine as! V8Engine } }`. This breaks on required initializers, though (`init(engine: Engine)` -> `init(engine: V8Engine)` in `Truck`).

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to override a stored property in swift. However, you are allowed to change the value of an inherited property while initialising an Instance.

Example:

```
class TypeA: NSObject {
}

class TypeB: TypeA {
}

class ObjectA {
    var type = [TypeA]()
}

class ObjectB: ObjectA {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        type = [TypeB]()
    }
}
```

Comment: but that would still require down casts to `TypeB`

Answer (score 0):

Another option, would be to use one Class within the other instead of using inheritance. Something like this:

```
class TypeA: NSObject {
}

class TypeB: TypeA {
}

class ObjectA {
    var type = [TypeA]()
}

class ObjectB: NSObject {
    private var obj = ObjectA()
    var type: [TypeB] {
        get{
            return obj.type as! [TypeB]
        }
        set {
            obj.type = newValue
        }
    }
}

var obj1 = ObjectB()
obj1.type = [TypeB()]
let test: TypeB = obj1.type[0]
```